# Cannot save "custom blob" to Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In javascript I am creating a blob from an array like so:

```
const a = new Blob([[1,2,3]]);
```

when I try to save this blob like:

```
this.afs.collection('events').doc(event.getID()).set({data: new Blob([[1,2,3]])}).then((some) => {
      debugger;
    })
```

I get an error:

> DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Blob object (found in field data)

What should I do to save a blob via JS to Firestore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your blob needs to be of type [`firebase.firestore.Blob`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Blob). Then using static `fromUint8Array`:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
...
const blob = firebase.firestore.Blob.fromUint8Array(new Uint8Array([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: How would you import that blob type?

Comment: With your code I get this error: "Uncaught Error: Function Blob.fromUint8Array() requires its first argument to be a Uint8Array, but it was: an array" I've suggested an edit with the working code. (`firebase.firestore.Blob.fromUint8Array(new Uint8Array([1,2,3]))`)